# Construct context-free grammar for $\{a^ib^jc^k : i\le j+k\}$

Tags: context-free-grammar

I'm looking through several of old exam sets in order to prepare for the exam and now I'm stuck on this exercise, where we have to construct a context-free grammar for the language:
$$L = \{a^ib^jc^k: i \le j+k  \}$$
The best solution I've obtained so far is the following that accepts $\{a^ib^jc^k: i = j+k  \}$:

$$\begin{align*}
&S\to aSc \mid D\\
&D\to aDb \mid \epsilon
\end{align*}$$

This context-free grammar will not create any strings that are not in the language but it will however not create all the possible strings we get with the condition $i \le j+k$.

How do I proceed to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just allow $S$ to produce $Sc$ and $D$ to produce $Db$, as well as what you already have.

Comment: Thanks, didn't expect it to be this simple but I've tried it on a few examples now and it works

Comment: @John: You’re welcome. It’s just a matter of making sure that every time you generate an $a$, you also generate a $b$ or a $c$, whichever is appropriate, while leaving yourself the option of generating $b$ or $c$ on its own as well.

Answer (score 0):

alas..it does not work  for $a^i b^j c^k$ where $i= j+k$
for

$S\rightarrow aSc|Sc|D$

$D\rightarrow aDb|\epsilon$

consider the parse tree

S

aSc

aaScc

aaSccc

aaDccc

aaccc

fail...  the solution is quite a bit more interesting but since I give it as an assignment I will cruelly keep it a secret..

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)