# Non-ambiguous CFG for an expression

Tags: context-free-grammar

I was practicing for an exam of CFG and I'm struggling with this CFG:

$L =\{a^ib^jc^k | j \le i+k\}$

I tried this CFG but is ambiguous:

$$S\to AXC$$
$$A\to aA|\lambda$$
$$C\to cC|\lambda$$
$$X\to YZ$$
$$Y\to aYb|\lambda$$
$$Z\to bZc|\lambda$$

If anyone can help me with this expression to make it unambiguous I will really appreciate it.

Comment: Similar [Construct context-free grammar for $\{a^ib^jc^k : i\le j+k\}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/544085/construct-context-free-grammar-for-aibjck-i-le-jk) obtained by using the formula searching tool https://approach0.xyz/

Comment: @JeanMarie One is $i \leq j+k$.  The other is $j \leq i + k$?

Comment: @Brian Moehring You are right. Thank you. I have modified my reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We distinguish between the $i\ge j$ and $i<j$ cases, making separate CFGs for each. In the first case a left nonterminal will generate $i-j$ excess $a$'s, a middle nonterminal will generate each remaining $a$ and $b$ in nested pairs and a right nonterminal will exclusively generate $c$'s:
$$S\to AXC$$
$$A\to aA|\varepsilon$$
$$X\to aXb|\varepsilon$$
$$C\to cC|\varepsilon$$
In the second case a left nonterminal will generate $i$ nested pairs of $a$ and $b$, a middle nonterminal will generate $b$-$c$ nested pairs (at least one this time since there is at least one more $b$ and there are at least as many $c$'s as $b$'s in the part not covered by the left nonterminal) and a right nonterminal is as before:
$$S\to XYC$$
$$Y\to bYc|bc$$
Thus the final unambiguous CFG is
$$S\to AXC|XYC$$
$$A\to aA|\varepsilon$$
$$X\to aXb|\varepsilon$$
$$Y\to bYc|bc$$
$$C\to cC|\varepsilon$$

Comment: Thank you so much!!! I didn't think in that way to solve the problem.